# How to delete outdated files?

Tags: windows, powershell, cmd, delete-file

I have a folder with a couple thousand files. Each file has been updated multiple times, some more than others. Each updated version gets a new number based on the revision. For example, the file "Apple.pdf" has been updated 3 times and now has the name "Apple3.pdf"

Is there any way I can mass delete all files that have updated versions without affecting the files that do not have updated versions? For example, in update 2 I receive 20 files with the name "???2.pdf" and now in update 3 I only have 10 updated files named "???3.pdf". I need to delete the out of date files from update 2, while keeping the ones that were unaffected by update 3.

Thanks in advance for any advice!

Comment: That's 2 questions: `1` How do I identify files from a set of files based on certain properties? `2` How do I delete a list of files? Which one are you having difficulty with?

Comment: And what have you tried so far?

Comment: I can delete files easy, but it is making sure that it is only deleting the files I have identified. So I would say I am having trouble identifying the set that needs to be deleted.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: This is not a specific programming-related question (consult [ask]), this is nothing but a task request, which is clearly off-topic here; please share your efforts and precisely describe what you have trouble with!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out a quick little script that will search a directory, in this case 'C:\temp\test', and find similarly named items with different version numbers in the file name. It then sorts the results in descending order and removes all but the first result. I tested it out and it works as expected:

Edit: I changed the value of $search to look for trailing numbers only, as recommended by LotPings, but I also added in the $_.extension to make sure that it was comparing against the same file formats. I have also updated the examples, since that has changed. Thanks for the recommendation!

```
$dir = "C:\temp\test"
$contents = gci $dir

$contents | % {
    $search = ($_.BaseName -replace "[0-9]*$","")+$_.Extension
    $search | % {
        $targets = gci $dir | ? {$_.Name -like "$(($search).Split(".")[0])*"} | sort -Descending
        $count = $targets.count
        $targets[1..($count-1)] | % {
            Remove-Item $_.FullName -Force
        }
    }
}
```

For example, a directory that looked like this originally

```
PS C:\Users\stack> gci c:\temp\test

    Directory: C:\temp\test


    Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         3/2/2017   7:33 AM                bak
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 2Two1.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 2Two2.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Four1.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Four2.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Four3.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Four4.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 One1.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Three1.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Three2.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Three3.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Twenty20.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Twenty21.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Two1.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Two2.txt
```

Will end up looking like this:

```
PS C:\Users\stack> gci c:\temp\test

    Directory: C:\temp\test


    Mode                LastWriteTime         Length Name
----                -------------         ------ ----
d-----         3/2/2017   7:33 AM                bak
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 2Two2.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Four4.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 One1.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Three3.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Twenty21.txt
-a----         3/1/2017   8:19 AM              0 Two2.txt
```

Comment: Also, I highly recommend backing up your data before trying that out! :)

Comment: As numbers could be part of a file name I'd reduce the strip to trailing numbers of BaseName. `$search = ($_.BaseName -replace "[0-9]*$","")`

Comment: While testing the `-whatif` option of `Remove-Item` is strongly recommended ;-)

Comment: What happens if the revisions get to `flle10.txt`, `file11.txt`, etc.

Comment: This line replaces digits with nothing, so it will continue to strip off the digits, even when you pass into double digits.
    $search = ($_.Name -replace '[0-9]',"")

Answer (score -1):

```
$Path = "C:\testData"
Get-ChildItem $Path -Include *2.pdf -Recurse | 
ForEach-Object ($_){Remove-Item $_.FullName}
```

Delete all files found in C:\testData with 2.pdf at the end of its full name and recursively check sub folders to do the same.

Comment: Not sure why this was downvoted, if his files are appended with a numerical number and he wants any files matching this to be removed then this is an example of how he can delete all files with the name2.pdf.